# Run newer version of mono without sudo

Tags: compilation, mono, debian, virtualhost

I'm on a virtual host with Debian, and it has an outdated version of mono.  I do not have sudo privileges.  I have compiled an updated version into my home directory with ./configure --prefix=$HOME.

How do I run my programs with the compiled version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a prefix of $HOME and assuming you have done a 'make install', add mono's bin dir to your path and test to see you are are picking up the correct/newer one:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
which mono
```

At that point, you can:

```
mono yourprogram.exe
```

Note: Instead of using your home directory as the prefix, you might want to install to a sub-directory to keep all those mono sub-dirs separate from your other HOME directories; i.e. Use --prefix=$HOME/mono when you autogen/configure mono.